# complex ternary operator in a while loop in c

Tags: c

```
  int a = 10;
  while (a > 8 ? (a--, (a > 7 ? a-- : a)): a--,a--) {
    printf("%d", a); // prints out 7
    break;
  }
```

premise: I know that the code is very badly written, this is not a real example, I will never write like that.

Can someone explain to me why it prints 7 instead of 8? it seems that the last `a--` is computed, but why? the expression is true...

Comment: It's important to mention that both `?:` and `,` are special case operators. `?:` has a sequence point between the evaluation of the 1st and 2nd or 3rd operand, and `,` has a sequence point between left-to-right evaluation of the operands. Without those, the code would have been completely bugged, without any well-defined result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comma operator `,` has lower precedence than ternary operator `?:`.

Breaking your expression up:

```
a > 8 // true because a = 10
  ? (
      a-- // executed, making a 9
      ,
      (
        a > 7 // true because a = 9
          ? a-- // executed, making a 8
          : a // not executed
      )
    )
  : a-- // not executed
,
a-- // executed, making a 7
```

Threfore `a` becomes `7` after evaluating the expression.

Answer (score 0):

First step: `a > 8`. Check if `a > 8`. it is true

Second step: `a--, (a > 7 ? a-- : a)`. Do `a--` (value of a is 9). Check if `a > 7`. It is true, so `a--` (value of a is 8)

Third step: `a--`. Do `a--` (after coma, last operation) (value of a is 7)